# Target :before on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a button I have created in CSS. It works great except when I hover over it, the entire area doesn't go green. Instead, part of it is a white block. How do I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/01vb0ybt/

```css
    button {
        font-size: 1em;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #1588cb;
        color: #1588cb;
        font-weight: 400;
        height: 60px;
        width: 300px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 25px 0 50px 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        -o-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    .full-circle {
        display:block;
        border: 1px solid #1588cb;
        width: 45px;
        /*
        -moz-border-radius: 45px / 36px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 45px / 36px;*/
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        -o-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        border-radius: 45px / 38px;
        height: 41px;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -17px;
        bottom: -17px;
    }
    .full-circle:before {
        content:'+';
        width: 47px;
        height: 26px;
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        left: -1px;
        top: -1px;
        line-height: 53px;
    }

button:hover, button:hover > span {
    background:green;
    color:white
}
}
```

```html
<button>News <span class="full-circle">
</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `button:hover > .full-circle:before` to format the background green. See the snippet

```css
button {
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #1588cb;
  color: #1588cb;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0 50px 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -o-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.full-circle {
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid #1588cb;
  width: 45px;
  /*
  -moz-border-radius: 45px / 36px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 45px / 36px;*/
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -o-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-radius: 45px / 38px;
  height: 41px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -17px;
  bottom: -17px;
}
.full-circle:before {
  content:'+';
  width: 47px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  line-height: 53px;
}
button:hover, 
button:hover > span, 
button:hover > .full-circle:before {
  background:green;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<button>News <span class="full-circle">
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt - just had to wait until the time elapsed for me to accept your answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Problem: when you hover over the button, you forgot to change the `background-color` of `span:before` (`background-color: white;`) to green.

Simply, add this `button:hover > span:before` to your css.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/01vb0ybt/2/)

```
 button:hover, 
 button:hover > span, 
 /* New selector */
 button:hover > span:before {
        background:green;
        color:white
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

add this style to your css

```
button:hover .full-circle:before {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS style.

```
button:hover .full-circle:before{
    background: green;
}
```